# Is car motor being lubricated with ignition off?

Tags: oil, lubrication

Is it ok to run car with ignition off (turning it off while in gear)? Or is oil pump electrical and stops running as soon as ignition is off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never come across a car that has an electric oil pump, but there are bound to be some special cases out there.  So the mechanical oil pump should be working.

You really need to say which car you have.

I wouldn’t recommend turning the ignition off while driving, since you may have electric power steering, electric power brakes, or the steering lock may come on.

Comment: Not only are the things you mention about electric steering, brakes, etc, in play, I know here in the States, it's actually illegal to drive without the vehicle running (I'm sure for just those reasons). I would bet other places around the world are exactly the same.